# Get records where decimal attribute is more than 0 in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Transaction` model in a Rails 3.1.0.rc4 app with a decimal attribute `amount`. I have records where the amount attribute is more than 0 as well as records where the amount attribute is less than 0. I want to get all the records where the amount is more than 0. I tried `Transaction.where('amount > 0')` and `Transaction.where('amount > 0.0')` but in both cases, all the records are returned, including the ones with a negative amount. When I run `Transaction.where('amount < 0')` or `Transaction.where('amount < 0.0')` no records are returned.

Is it possible to do these types of queries on decimal attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with SQLite and your migrations - if you open up your SQLite database and run `SELECT typeof(amount) FROM transactions LIMIT 1` you'll see that Rails is creating your decimal field as a BLOB type instead of the decimal REAL type.

I'm not sure if this is a Rails bug or not, but for the time being you can get around it by casting the amount in your where clause:

```
Transaction.where("CAST(amount AS REAL) > 0")
```

You can also get around this by using straight SQL in your migration with the `execute` method to create `amount` as a REAL field to begin with (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
Transaction.where('amount > ?', 0.0)
```

Comment: Yes, I am actually doing this, but I left it out for brevity.